# Validating Decimal Numbers

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form and I am using jQuery validation plugin to validate it. Now I am trying to validate decimal number input.

I have tried the following code, but its not working. Is the problem with the regular expression or the way of writing the custom rule is wrong in my code?

```
 rules: {
      paid_amount: {
              required:true,
                      rexp: ^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$
      },

   }
     },

 messages: {
             paid_amount: {
                      required: "Enter Paid Amount",
              rexp:"Decimal Numbers Only"
    },  

     }
});
```

Comment: _"but its not working"_ can you elaborate some more please?

Comment: are you using a custom rule for a specific reason? There is a number rule already in the validation library.

Comment: @gdoron .It doesn't show any error message if I type alphabets in the input.

Comment: @dSquared Yes you are right there is a number rule already, but if you type any decimal number it will show an error message.

Comment: @gdoron Take a look at my answer below, the digits method is for only digits and number is for decimal number.

Comment: @dSquared Sorry, I was wrong and you were right.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the number validation method found [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number)

From the docs:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      number: true
    }
  }
});
```

In your case:

```
rules: {
    paid_amount: {
        required:true,
        number: true
    }
},
messages: {
    paid_amount: {
        required: "Enter Paid Amount",
        number: "Decimal Numbers Only"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this exact same thing but .01 doesn't pass. ANy ideas as to why?

Comment: @Mike_OBrien I just checked on a local form and it works as expected. It could be something with other rules / functions in your code. I'd have to see the relavent code to suggest an answer. It might be worthwhile to post this as a questions with the code.

Comment: question poseted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395552/jquery-validation-01-failing)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with jquery validator plugin, sorry but
your regular expression is valid.

another approach would be

```
var reg = "/^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/"; //reg pattern<br/>
if(reg.test("1.23"))//validate
{
 //do something <br/>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery validator also supports decimal validation using range method.

```
factor:
      {
        required: true,
        range:[0.08,20.09]  
      },
```

Read more [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/range-method/) and  [demo](http://codepen.io/prasanthmj/pen/lvKoG) here.

Comment: what if i want to allow comma instead of dot, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery isNumeric function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the method 'rexg'. You should use 'pattern'. Example:

```
paid_amount: {
     required:true,
     pattern: ^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$
}
```