# Boostrap Validation: not to validate decimal value like .00

Tags: jquery, bootstrapvalidator

I have input field in this field only allow decimal values (i.e)1.00,500.00,678.00 (after decimal only two zeros). how to achieve this using jquery bootstrap validator.

`fields: { amount_pay:{ validators: { notEmpty: { message: 'This field is required and can\'t be empty' }, integer: { message: 'The value is not an integer' }`

actually this is my validation,I am using integer but when i focus out i must to add .00.But doing like this it shows validation error.How to solve this

Comment: Could this be useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790261/validating-decimal-numbers

Comment: i checked already.No use

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your work?

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom validator by providing a function that receives a jQuery element as an argument and returns an error message if the field is invalid. Thus you should activate the validation via JavaScript:

hope this will solve your issue cheers implement this

```
$('#myForm').validator({
custom: {
amount_pay: function ($el) {
var text = $el.val;
if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) && (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 3))  
{
     return "Please insert valid number."
}          
}
});
```

Please refer to the documentation: http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/